# stop changing value in edit_in_place plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am using [edit_in_place plugin](http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html) .

I am updating the value in **database** also.That's why I am using confirm popup before editing the value. When user clicks on yes button then it should update otherwise it should not update. yes operation is working superb but when I am clicking on **NO** then it's ok that value is not changing in database but on the web page it seems visible.How can I stop to change on web page also.

This is my **HTML** code :

```
<?
   $e_c_query = "select * from category order by id desc";
   $e_c_result = mysql_query($e_c_query);
   while($e_c_row = mysql_fetch_object($e_c_result))
   {
 ?>
       <tr class="highlighter">
           <td class="editable-2" id="<?=$e_c_row->id?>" align="center"><div id="<?=$e_c_row->id?>"><?=$e_c_row->category_name?></div></td>

      </tr>
<?
   }
?>
```

**Jquery** code :

```
$('.editable-2').editable({onSubmit: submitData});
        function submitData (content) {
            //alert('aa');
            if(content.previous==content.current || content.current == "")
                {

                }
                else{
                    var yes = confirm("Are you sure to Edit");
                    if(yes)
                            {
                            $.get('change_categ.php', {already_categ_val : content.previous, categ_name: content.current },function(data){
                            if(data=='1')
                                {
                                    document.getElementById('manual_msg_div').className='msg-div';
                                    document.getElementById('manual_msg_div').innerHTML="Category Updated Successfullly";
                                    $('#manual_msg_div').append('<br/>');
                                }
                        });
                        }else{

                        }
                }


        }
```

**PHP** code

```
<?    $already_categ_val = $_GET['already_categ_val'];
    $categ_name = $_GET['categ_name'];

    mysql_query("update category set category_name='".$categ_name."' where category_name='".$already_categ_val."'") or die(mysql_error());
    //echo "update category set category_name='".$categ_name."' where category_name='".$categ_name."'";
    if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1)
        echo "1";
    else {
        echo "0";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if(yes) {
 //...
}
else {
   this.html(content.previous);
}
```